# Why can't I write to the .txt file?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to write in a txt file, but I get

> access to the path is denied

every time. I have tried many suggestions from google searches. None of them work: like start as admin, give full access to different users, etc.

The test.txt is in the root folder of the project ex: "MyProject/test.txt"..

This is the code:

```
private void LikeIt()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {       
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("test.txt")))
        {
            foreach (var line in ReadFile())
            {
                // If the line doesn't contain the same ID, write the line to the file. 
                if (!line.Contains(App.Moviess.Filmerna[index].id.ToString()))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(App.Moviess.Filmerna[index].id.ToString() + "\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private List<string> ReadFile()
{
    List<string> lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\MovieStarz\MovieStarz\WriteText.txt").ToList();
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Are you logged into windows as administrator?

Comment: Is the file marked as readonly?
Have you run the application as Administrator?
Is the file open else where?

What have you tried?

Comment: Have you started visual studios as admin?

Comment: I have tried all of that... i think i will change to store the ID in sqlite insteed... :/

Comment: Random downvote lol - question is OKAY imho. Probably some windows hater kid :) Regarding question: Did you look at exception details? No insights from there? Did you try to add some share mode just to see if it changes behavior?

Comment: I'd say it's downvoted due to the lack of detail.

Issue, code. Expecting someone to debug the code for them. You should put exception details in your questions, also include things you've already tried.

Comment: Which line throws the exeption?

Comment: The ``openWrite()`` line I presume from the question text.

Comment: If the file is in "MyProject/test.txt", it doesn't mean it is in "MyProject/bin/AnyCPU" (or similar) where the program might expect it. Furthermore, it is not guaranteed that the current path is the path of the exe file. It's better to operate with abolute paths.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: The file to be read is another file.

Comment: Ok, on mobile phone and didn't see that, thxs

Comment: @Liero here:
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("test.txt")))

Comment: Is it a WPF or an UWP app? Can't be both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
var sourceFile = "text.txt";
var targetFile = @"C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\MovieStarz\MovieStarz\WriteText.txt";
var id = App.Moviess.Filmerna[index].id.ToString();

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFile)
    .Where(l => l.Contains(id))
    .ToArray();

File.AppendAllLines(targetFile, lines);
```

This code opens file, reads content and closes it. Then opens another file, writes what necessary and closes it.

Opening and closing is done automatically and you never have opened two files at once.

If this does not work:

- your file may be locked by another process. (try to restart PC)
- your program does not have permission to access the file (try to put the file out of C:\Users)
- since you are doing it asynchronously, you have to guarantee that two threads won't access the file at the same time:

  ```
  private static readonly object fileLock = new object();
  private void LikeIt()
  {
      Task.Run(() =>
      {       
          lock(fileLock){
             //do the stuff here
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: @Newbie1337: what part of my answer has helped you?

Comment: restartPC, use the var for source and targetfile, and the lock.. after that it worked.. :) soo thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe file that you want to write is already opened by some other program. So you need to set FileShare property,

```
using (Stream fs = System.IO.File.Open("test.txt", 
                                      FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                                      FileAccess.Write, 
                                      FileShare.ReadWrite)) 
{
  using(var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs))
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: FileShare.Read might be sufficient - if on the other hand the other app locked exclusively... it won't matter.

Comment: I get "StreamWriter cant bee used like a method"

Comment: he forgot ``new`` I think - maybe an overdose of F# programming, uh? :)

Comment: oh, why did i not see that :)

Answer (score -3):

You should open your file in `using` directive. If you don't, your file remains open, and cannot be accessed after:

```
using(var fs = File.OpenWrite("test.txt"))
using(var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs))
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: some explanations on why and more important when (IDisposable) to use using would be good.

Comment: Well sure. Maybe some examples from unmanaged code also? Garbage collection lecture will be nice too.

Comment: well it would help people to understand why you suggest to use using, not everyone has the same knowledge...